# Angular directive two way databinding fails

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a dropdown directive with a function which sets the active item in the dropdown:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .directive('customDropDown', function ($filter, calculationsFactory) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'template/custom-drop-down/custom-drop-down.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        resources: '=',
        activeResource: '=',
      },
      link: function postLink(scope) {
        scope.setActiveResource = function(resource){
          scope.activeResource = resource;
        };

      }
    };
  });
```

Markup:

```
  <custom-drop-down resources="medias" active-resource="activeMedia"></custom-drop-down>
```

DirectiveTemplate:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle style="width:100%;" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
    {{activeResource.title}} <span class="caret pull-right" style="margin-top:8px;"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="resource in filtredResources"
        ng-click="setActiveResource(resource)"
        ng-class="{active: resource === activeResource}">
      <a href>{{resource.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Problem is that the function don't two way bind "activeMedia" in this case. It does not get updated.

I tried to replicate the case in jsfiddle but there it works. Anything I could have missed?

**Update**

I have identified the issue.
My directive is placed within the accordion directive from ui-bootstrap:

```
 <accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Resources" is-open="true">
       <custom-drop-down resources="medias" active-resource="activeMedia"></custom-drop-down>
    </accordion-group>
 </accordion>
```

If I move my directive outside the accordion directive, it works. So somehow the accordion directive is interfering with my directive. Possible to solve without modifying the code for ui-bootstrap?

Comment: What's the data type of `activeResource` (`activeMedia` too)? If it's an array then changing it like that will make it point to a different reference, something that will break AngularJS's internal `$digest` loop (it compares stuff by reference).

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv activeResource is a object. resources is an array with objects.

Comment: Are you calling `setActiveResource` in an `ng-click` or some other built-in AngularJS directive?

Comment: Show the directive's template. There is a pretty good chance you are calling Angular from DOM event without `$apply`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Yes. Have added the directive template in question.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/psucyfuf/1/

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Yeha it works also if I move the exact code to another project. Must be something wierd in my project. I

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv 1.2.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it is a scoping issue, as discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

For elements inside angular-bootstrap controls you need to use `$parent.` as a prefix on scope variables.

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Resources" is-open="true">
       <custom-drop-down resources="$parent.medias" active-resource="$parent.activeMedia"></custom-drop-down>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```